# How to stop optimization (e.g. NMinimize) after reaching target value

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Suppose we have some function `f[x,y]` that we want to optimize in way that we are only interested in values `(x,y)` that guarantee our function value is below some value `target`. See the following MWE:

```
f[x_, y_] := f[x, y] = x^2 - 4*x + y^2 - y - x*y;

findMin[target_, steps_] := Block[{nbr = -1},
  solsOpt = NMinimize[
    f[x, y],
    {x, y},
    Method -> "NelderMead",
    (*EvaluationMonitor:>{nbr += 1; If[Mod[nbr, steps] == 0, Print["Step: ", nbr," ; Current value: ",f[x,y], " ; parameters: ",{x,y}],Print]}*)
    EvaluationMonitor :> {nbr += 1; If[Mod[nbr, steps] == 0, Print["Step: ", nbr," ; Current value: ", f[x, y], " ; parameters: ", {x, y}], Print] || If[f[x, y] <= target, Abort[], Print]}
   ];
  Print["Number of iterations: ", nbr];
  Print["Final value: ", solsOpt[[1]]];
  Return[solsOpt];
  ]
```

Of course `findMin[-5,1]` stops after a few iterations and I can read the values `(x,y)` that satisfy my criterion. However, I need to do that for a bunch of different functions `f` inside a `ParallelTable` structure, that in the end holds (function_index, final value, parameter values). By aborting no values are stored. What I want is something like "After reaching target, just assume optimization is finished and go on with the next one". Is that possible with the built-in function(s)?

Comment: [`CheckAbort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CheckAbort.html)?  Perhaps with `Reap` and `Sow`...

Comment: `FindInstance[f[x, y] <= -5, {x, y}]`?

Comment: Might be able to do it with `StepMonitor`, e.g. having it `Throw` a result if it is sufficiently good. If you have in mind a particular threshold you can also make it into a constraint.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the hint to `CheckAbort`- I did not know of this function. I will definitely give it a try although george2079 already posted a working answer. Always so many ways to reach the goal :)

Comment: @Rahul Also thanks. That will work in this case for the MWE but my actual problem is by far too complicated to be solved via `FindInstance`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks as well! I guess what you were hinting at is pretty much what george2079 gave as an answer, right?

Comment: Sorry, I should have paid closer attention. Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Can you please expand on why `PrecisionGoal`/`AccuracyGoal` are not suited to this application? Is it that the target value is not significantly smaller than the value one might get from random parameter values? Incidentally, you will probably find `FindMinimum` much faster than `NMinimize` if you only want a sufficient decrease rather than to find a true minimum (which the Nelder-Mead algorithm often cannot do anyway).

Comment: @OleksandrR. I already tried to use that (forgot to mention that above) but very likely I just did not get the full understanding of what both do. From what I got in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4631369) I tried setting both to `5` since I am interested in values slighty less than `10^(-4)` for the real problem. However, the optimization did not stop at all. But I'd appreciate correcting my usage since it is most likely wrong. - see next comment for continuation

Comment: I also tried `FindMinimum` but it tended to find the same results as `NMinimize` in my real problem. But now after I know how to stop, it might probably find results faster and I will give it a try again. - Also as an aside:  In another comment to one of my questions you explained why `NelderMead` will probably not work that good. I tried different ones like `DifferentialEvolution`and `SimulatedAnnealing` and also other algorithm parameters as explained in _F. Gao, L. Han_, Comp. Opt. and Appl., **51**, 259-277. However, `NelderMead` with standard parameters led to best results in most cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Catch/Throw`:

```
 findMin[target_, steps_] := 
    Block[{nbr = -1}, 
     solsOpt = 
        ReleaseHold@Catch@NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y},
          Method -> "NelderMead", 
          EvaluationMonitor :> {nbr += 1; 
          If[Mod[nbr, steps] == 0, 
          Print["Step: ", nbr, " ; Current value: ", f[x, y], 
               " ; parameters: ", {x, y}], Print] || 
          If[f[x, y] <= target, Print["good enough"];
                Throw[{f[x, y], {HoldForm[x] -> x, HoldForm[y] -> y}}], 
     Print]}];
     Print["Number of iterations: ", nbr];
     Print["Final value: ", solsOpt];
     solsOpt]


 findMin[-5, 1] (* three iterations, stop for threshold *)
```

> {-6.1742, {x -> 2.2116, y -> 1.00612}}

```
 findMin[-50, 1]  (* 89 iterations , regular convergence *)
```

> {-7., {x -> 3., y -> 2.}}

Aside , I don't know why you have the symbol `Print` in there a few times not applied to any arguments..

Also, aside from the question you can do `NMinimize[fn = f[x, y],...` then use the symbol `fn` in your conditional `If[fn <= target ..` so avoiding redundant  evaluation of the function.

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer. I did not think of `Throw` which is really well-suited for this case... Regarding the `Print` symbols: they are just "dummies" and have no special meaning. Also thanks for the side remark considering the usage `NMinimize[fn=f[x,y],...]`; I will probably implement that :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: I will not accept the answer yet, although it works. Just t want to wait for a couple of days if someone posts another answer.

Comment: @george2079, thank you for the answer. Eventually, NMimimize with `Catch-Throw` returns unevaluated expression (I'm on MMA 12.0). It doesn't happen with Reap-Sow, though. Before I did not encounter such a problem. Do you know why can in be?