# How to make NMinimize stop running when EvaluationMonitor gets stuck

Tags: mathematical-optimization, monitoring

I have a some optimisation problem (though `gmmobjg` is a bit complicated to reproduce it here, I've posted of [git](https://github.com/garej/blp)).

The code for optimization is:

```
NMinimize[gmmobjg[test], list, Method -> "NelderMead", AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
EvaluationMonitor :> {Print[gmmobjg[test]]}]
```

I need to observe progress, so use `EvaluationMonitor`.
I get some fine results printed, but at some point 'EvaluationMonitor' gets stuck forever while the code keeps running. Moreover, launched with last achived parameters values, it allows to minimize further (with the same algo).

I could `Abort Evaluation` but what are gentle ways to make it to stop running if we do not know *ex ante* how long the whole optimization and each evaluation cycle could take?

---

**Edit**

[TimeUsed[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeUsed.html) seems to be a proper way.

Comment: [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstrained.html)?

Comment: Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82845/22013) helpful? Sorry, but I won't be inventing an MWE to play with.

Comment: There's a cycle of evaluation: `obj[test]`, then `EvaluationMonitor`, if a step then `StepMonitor`, then repeat. It cannot get stuck at `EvaluationMonitor` while the code keeps running. I think you reach a value of `test` for `obj[test]` is taking an extremely long time.

Comment: @MichaelE2, may be ‘stuck’ is not a good term here, but why may this happen? If I relaunch the cycle with last found value of test, it proceeds to diminish obj value until next ‘very long’ lock in. I do not know what happens behind the scene. That is why I decided to check it with ‘TimeUsed’ and relaunch manually.

Comment: I don't know how to tell without the code for `obj`. Since Nelder-Mead keeps n+1 points, you need to restart with those values or it is not following the same next step, which might explain why it runs for a while. It could be a bug in `NMinimize`, but that seems much less likely.

Comment: @MichaelE2, it was tricky to make an MWE, so I've made a repository with the code where `obj` is `gmmobjg`. Please, take a look at: [https://github.com/garej/blp](https://github.com/garej/blp). Any suggestions will be welcome!